# Dynamic title with ireport

Tags: jasper-reports

I have a report done with a crosstab which makes the size of the report different according to the size of the returned results.

Thus the generated excel file can have different sizes (more or less columns), what makes the title not centered .

I want to get a title that stretches with the width of the report and gets centred accoding to the new width of the report.

I have been told that this is not possible with ireport so i wanted to make sure maybe i will find an answer .

Answer (score 0):

**Yes**, In iReport you **cannot** increase the width of a component dynamically.You can only increase the height dynamically.

Comment: Thank you so much Mani !